# How to find the text of nested div by xpath in Selenium Java?

Tags: xpath

I tried to use this code to find the text of the nested div but I get no text.
I am trying to get directly to the nested div to avoid any issue in case the development team changes the structure of the site.

I tried to save the text "$89.67 / mo" and save it in a variable but I guess it did not work because the div has a parent div. Also I am trying to get the confirmation number`enter code here`

premium = r.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'amount')]")).getText();

Below is the HTML code and I want to get the text that says $89.67 / mo
and the confirmation number 442686

```
          div id="quoteUser" class="row padTop hidden-phone">
          <div class="span4">
          <p class="padLeft padTop long-text">
           vdueiapxibupkdf Testprodquote, <span class="skyblue">Policy 
           Holder</span><br>
            3334 test dr<br>
             City, CA<br>
             Email: test@test.com<br>
             Primary Phone: 254-000-0000
             </p>
             <p class="padLeft padTop skyblue">
            Quote date: April 16, 2015<br>
            Confirmation No.: <b>442686</b>
           </p>
           </div>
           <div class="span6 print-block">
           <div class="quotemedia skyblue">
            <p class="blue clearfix">Your Quote for 1 Driver(s), 1 
            Vehicle(s)</p>
           <div class="amount-container no-bord">
            <div class="amount">$89.67 / mo.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange... the same code worked for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'amount')]")).getText()
```

The following xpath also worked:

```
//*[contains(@class,'amount')]
```

Code that worked for confirmation number:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'padLeft padTop skyblue')]/b")).getText()
```

It would be better if your dev team could use IDs for HTML tags instead of you having to rely on class attributes.